# Using Tkinter to export user input to a .csv file

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a tkinter code setup that will give the user seven entry prompts, and a "Submit" button. I want to be able to export whatever the user types into the entry box, to a .csv file. I have used the Python tkinter docs, and many other resources, including this website, but cannot find an answer. This is the code i have so far:

```
import Tkinter 
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import csv

class App(Frame):
    def tile():
        Label(text='Enter Information Below').pack(side=TOP,padx=15,pady=15)

def output(self):
    with open('WorkOrderLog.csv', 'a') as f:
        w=csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

        Label(text='Name:').pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)
        Entry(root, width=10).pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)

        Label(text='1:').pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)
        Entry(root, width=10).pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)

        Label(text='2:').pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)
        Entry(root, width=10).pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)

        Label(text='3:').pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)
        Entry(root, width=10).pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)

        Label(text='4:').pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)
        Entry(root, width=10).pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)

        Label(text='5:').pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)
        Entry(root, width=10).pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)

        Label(text='6:').pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)
        Entry(root, width=10).pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)

        Button(root, text='Submit', command=w.writerow([Entry,Entry,Entry,Entry,Entry,Entry,Entry])).pack(side=RIGHT,padx=5,pady=5)

def __init__(self, master=None):
    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.pack()
    self.output()

root=Tk()
root.title('Auto Logger')
root.geometry('1000x100')
app=App(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.mainloop()
```

Im lost as tho where to go from here. I have researched how to to use the "get()" function, as that seems to be a common answer, but my knowledge of tkinter is limited. Any and all help is tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right track using get(), which will return the contents of a tkinter Entry widget.

I have used a single Entry to illustrate how you can accomplish retreiving text from Entry widgets and writing the contents to a .csv file.

```
from tkinter import * 
import csv

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.output()

    def output(self):
        Label(text='Name:').pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)
        self.e = Entry(root, width=10)
        self.e.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)

        self.b = Button(root, text='Submit', command=self.writeToFile)
        self.b.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=5,pady=5)

    def writeToFile(self):
        with open('WorkOrderLog.csv', 'a') as f:
            w=csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            w.writerow([self.e.get()])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tk()
    root.title('Auto Logger')
    root.geometry('1000x100')
    app=App(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
    root.mainloop()
```

By creating the Entry and assigning it to self.e, you are able to access the text value by calling self.e.get() in the App class' writeToFile function.

Comment: I know I am years late to this post but I am trying a similar task. I ran this code on my machine and when the app popped up I typed my name and clicked submit but nothing happened